# Properties of solution to Schrödinger equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, quantum-mechanics

Given a Schrödinger equation with, let's say continuous, periodic potential

$$-y''(x)+V(x)y(x)=\lambda y(x)$$

where $V(x+1)=V(x)$ and $V$ is even, i.e. for $x \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ we have $V(x+\frac{1}{2})=V(\frac{1}{2}-x)$

then it seems that the two solutions $y_1,y_2$ with initial conditions $y_1(\lambda,0)=1, y_1'(\lambda,0)=0$ and $y_2(\lambda,0)=0,y_2'(\lambda,0)=1$

have the property that the function $f(\lambda):=y_1(\lambda,1)+\alpha y_2(\lambda,1)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, has non-vanishing derivative (w.r.t. $\lambda$) whenever $\left\lvert f(\lambda) \right\rvert <1.$ This is something I noticed in some numerical calculations.

This is why I think this may hold:
This seems to be an extension of Floquet theory, where the Floquet discriminant, in this case, $y_1(\lambda,1)$ has the property that $\frac{d}{d\lambda} y_1(\lambda,1)$ does not vanish if $\left\lvert y_1(\lambda,1)\right\rvert <1.$

Does anybody know if this conjecture is true and has a reference for a proof of this fact?

Comment: @ChristianRemling sorry, there were a typo in the question, now it should make more sense.

Comment: @ChristianRemling the symmetry of the potential implies that $y_1(1,\lambda)=y_2'(1,\lambda)$

Comment: @WillieWong ' denotes now exclusively differentiation w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: I suspect this is false, but it does seem to hold for $V=0$ (if my calculations are correct). If this is correct, then it probably won't be easy to find a counterexample.